# Convert string to correct format for jQuery fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout

I need to format a string in order to pass it as a duration for jQuery's `fadeOut`, the string is a CSS variable that I access in my JavaScript.

jQuery's `fadeOut` accepts a number or keyword string, i want to format the CSS var as a number and convert it to milliseconds so it can be used as a duration value for `fadeOut`

The CSS var is for `transition` timing so CSS authors can set this value in a few different formats, e.g:

```
300ms
0.9s
.4s
```

I'm setting the CSS var in my LESS stylesheet

```
:root {
    --transition__duration: @transition__duration; // 300ms
}
```

and accessing it in the JS (simplified)

```
var transitionVarName = '--transition__duration',
    transitionVar = getComputedStyle(docRoot).getPropertyValue(transitionVarName),
    transitionDuration = transitionVar ? transitionVar : 300,
    fadeSpeed = clean(transitionDuration);

    element.fadeOut(fadeSpeed)

    clean: function (str) {
        var num = str;

        return parseFloat(num);
    }
```

`parseFloat(num)` works for values like `300ms` which gives me `300` but when i pass something like `.3s` it returns `3`, i understand this is the expected behaviour for `parseFloat` but I'm not sure about the math needed to get the format I want, e.g

```
300ms // 300
0.9s // 900
.4s // 400
```

EDIT:

The solution

```
getFadeSpeed: function () {
    let docRoot = document.documentElement,
        transitionVarName = '--transition__duration',
        transitionVar = getComputedStyle(docRoot).getPropertyValue(transitionVarName),
        transitionDuration = transitionVar ? transitionVar : '300',
        num = transitionDuration;

    if (num.includes(".") || num.endsWith('s') && !num.endsWith('ms')) {
        num = num.replaceAll('s', '');
        num = num * 1000;
    }

    return parseFloat(num);
}
```

Comment: Well its not that complicated math, if it has dot, take in multiply by 100?...

Comment: https://github.com/ryanfarber/time-string-parser ?

Comment: @ikiK Maybe i should have said logic rather than math, but I'm guessing I need some regex to deal with cases like `3s` becoming 300 when it should be 3000. Either that or it's late and I need more coffee, always a possibility.

Comment: @Sysix Thanks but I'm hoping this can be done with some good ol' plain JS, or even jQuery, it's a legacy app so it's already available.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright this is pure js. look at package.json there are no deps

Comment: @Sysix You're right. It's late and I do need more coffee, thanks I'll take a look.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright I think you need a good nap :) your welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something on the fly, (its late here too... Maye I didn't cover it all)

```js
let arr = ["300ms", "0.9s", ".4s", "3s"]

arr.forEach(time => {

  time = "0" + time;
  //console.log(time)
  if (time.includes(".") || time.endsWith('s') && !time.endsWith('ms')) {
    time = time.replaceAll('s', '');
    time = time * 1000;
  }
  time = parseFloat(time)
  console.log(time)
});
```

So you should have I think:

```
clean: function(str) {
  var num = str;

  num = "0" + num;

  if (num.includes(".") || num.endsWith('s') && !num.endsWith('ms')) {
    num = num.replaceAll('s', '');
    num = num * 1000;
  }

  return parseFloat(num);
}
```