# I am trying to import SASS variables into my javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, sass

I an attempt to get my `.js` file to see SASS variables, I've followed this [article](https://css-tricks.com/getting-javascript-to-talk-to-css-and-sass/). This question features an error I get from attempting this method. But even if you have had success importing SASS variables in javascript in another way, please do share your success with me!

I will show you the code I've written and the error I get. First the code:

My `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {

    entry: `./sass.js`, 
    output: {
      path: `${__dirname}`, 
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',

    // ...
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
        },
        // ...
        ]
    }  
}
```

My `.scss` file:

```
$kiwi: red;

:export {
    kiwi: $kiwi,
}
```

My `.js` file:

```js
import variables from './webpack_sass.scss';
```

My `.html` file (which I've checked does correctly see `bundle.js`):

```html
<head>
  <script type="module" src="./bundle.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have installed `webpack` & `webpack-cli`. Here's a picture of my `package.json` file:

[image]

The error I get is:

[image]

---

Comment: variables is an identifier not a string - it should not have quotes.

Comment: Thanks @RandyCasburn. I have made this change and've updated the error message

Comment: Depending on what you need to do with the values you could set the SASS vars as CSS vars and get/set them with JS.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright I'm really wanting to use SASS variables as there're so many articles that claim it's easily done if you type in 'import sass variables into javascript' into google. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright I ended up trying your method without success. I might post a new question troubleshooting it. Or do you have a reliable source you could pass on that instructs me how to do it? It works when the value of the CSS variable is a regular CSS property-value but not when it's a SASS variable. What gets logged is the literal letters of these SASS variable e.g. `$color`.

Comment: @tonitone120 Take a look at this question, it's a similar method to what I proposed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287677/convert-string-to-correct-format-for-jquery-fadeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:export` syntax is a sugar that `css-loader` adds, all you need to do is to enable the [css-modules](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules) feature.

You have 2 choices:

1. add `.module.scss` suffix to your file (since css-module is enabled by default for it)
2. enable css-modules to all `.scss` imports, by specifying

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  entry: `./sass.js`,
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}`,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  mode: 'development',

  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true, // <- this enables css-modules for all imports
            },
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      // ...
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: I've put a picture at the bottom of my post to show what the config file looks like now. Still get the same error

Comment: Can you add the entire webpack.config? My suggestion is not ment to be as copy-paste solution

Comment: You mean integrate it into what I already had? I tried. Can you give it a go in your answer?

Comment: I've integrated the loader option in your code... but pls try with the file name option first... (rename your css file to `.module.scss` instead of `.scss`)

Comment: I was able to get it to work by 1. using your `webpack.config.js` file (the one in the article doesn't work) & 2. installing `sass css-loader style-loader sass-loader` which the article doesn't mention. Because I i) feel like I'm copy'n'pasting the `.config` file without understanding what's going on ii) I use react and am not confident modifying the `webpack.config.js` file in there & iii) have had success assigning the value of SASS variables to CSS variables and importing these CSS variables into `.js`, I'm going to stop pursuing this solution. I'm okay with IE not supporting CSS variables.