# Vue CLI 5 with Vuetify SCSS variables and CSS imports

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-5

I work for an organization that try to migrate a project from Vue CLI 4 to Vue CLI 5.
The project uses Vuetify and we have SCSS files that are used in the `styles/variables.scss` file (required by Vuetify to customize style) and also used in Vue components files via `@import` (SCSS variables sometimes need to be in the `<script>` section).
Here some example that show how SCSS variables are used through the app:

```
// styles/variables.scss

@import "colors.scss";
$some-vuetify-sass-variable: $color // from (colors.scss)
```

```
// plugins/vuetify.js

import { primaryColor } from "@/style/colors.scss";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const options = {
  theme: {
    dark: false,
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: primaryColor,
        // ...
      },
    },
  },
};

export default new Vuetify(options);
```

```
// Component.vue

<template>
  <v-chip
    :color="clearPrimaryColor"
    text-color="primary"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { clearPrimaryColor } from "@/style/colors.scss";
export default {
  name: "Component",
  created() {
    this.clearPrimaryColor = clearPrimaryColor;
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.some-class {
  background-color: $clearPrimaryColor 
}
</style>
```

During the Vue CLI migration, we also tried to upgrade some Vuetify dependencies (`sass` and `vuetify-loader`). Upgrading `sass` from 8 to 10 version triggers a compile sass error.

With this reproduction branch: https://github.com/KevinFabre/vue-cli-5-vuetify-scss-variables-in-js (sass 8.0.0), the project does compile.
And for this one: [https://github.com/KevinFabre/vue-cli-5-vuetify-scss-variables-in -js/tree/error/sass-error](https://github.com/KevinFabre/vue-cli-5-vuetify-scss-variables-in-js/tree/error/sass-error) (sass 10.0.0), it does not compile:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                

 error  in ./src/styles/app.module.scss

Syntax Error: SassError: This file is already being loaded.

  ╷
2 │ @import "app.module.scss";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/styles/variables.scss 2:9   @import
  src/styles/app.module.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
```

**Is there extra Vue CLI 5 configuration to allow CSS import in JS while using Vuetify sass override ?**

We've submitted issues to vuetify-loader and Vue CLI but didn't receive any reply for now:

- https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/issues/234
- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/7083

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.4.1",
    "@mdi/font": "^6.5.95",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.4.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "^4.4.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.4.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "eslint": "^7.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^1.1.5",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vuetify": "^1.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.11",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "style-resources-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-style-resources-loader": "^0.1.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.6",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.3",
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components must avoid importing files that are already imported in the global variables stylesheet (`src/styles/variables.scss`). This was the case with `app.module.scss` (loaded in `src/styles/variables.scss` and in `src/components/HelloWorld.vue`), causing the error about the file being loaded twice.

One solution is to move the color definitions from `app.module.scss` into its own file, and import that in `variables.scss` instead of `app.module.scss`. Then, components could import `app.mdoule.scss` without running into the original problem.

```css
/* src/styles/app.module.scss *
:export {
  whitecolor: $white-color;
  darkcolor: $dark-color;
  lightcolor: $light-color;
  mediumcolor: $medium-color;
  alertcolor: $alert-color;
  lightblackcolor: $light-black-color;
  blackcolor: $black-color;
}
```

```css
/* src/styles/colors.scss */
$white-color: #fcf5ed;
$dark-color: #402f2b;
$light-color: #e6d5c3;
$medium-color: #977978;
$alert-color: #cb492a;
$light-black-color: #706e72;
$black-color: #414042;
```

```css
/* src/styles/variables.scss */
@import "~vuetify/src/styles/settings/_colors.scss";
@import "colors.scss";

$material-light: (
  background: map-get($grey, "lighten-1")
);
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-cli-fix-sass-file-already-loaded?file=src%2Fstyles%2Fvariables.scss)

Comment: worth noting that the 'module' naming is important. [css-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64641969/9632731) basically requires it

Answer (score 0):

This basically pertains to duplicate parsing of the import files, declared in your vuejs app.

There are 2 ways to solve it:

1. Use @use instead of @import where you are getting the Sass import error. Like, `@import "app.module.scss";` becomes `@use "app.module.scss";`
2. Other alternative is to downgrade the sass-loader library to "^8.0.2"

Let me know if the above solutions work for you, meanwhile i will update my answer if i find any new solution.

Comment: 1. `@use` leads to a loop: `Syntax Error: SassError: Module loop: this module is already being loaded.`
2. Downgrading sass-loader to 8 is not a viable solution, stable is already 12.